# Como passar multiplos viewmodel para uma única view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho minha view, ela depende de uma viewmodel.

Mas nessa mesma view, eu adiciono itens referente a principal com uma modal do bootstrap, e nela preciso de outra viewmodel para as validações.

Como eu passo 2 viewsmodels em uma única view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma dentro da outra.

```
public class ViewModelPrincipal 
{
    public ViewModelDeValidacoes ViewModelDeValidacoes { get; set; }
}
```