# Como atribuir o valor de uma TempData["Teste"] ou ViewBag.Id a um input html?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5, asp.net

Queria saber como faço para pegar o valor da minha variável tempData e colocar em um input do html, em value talvez... alguém poderia me ajudar?

Código abaixo:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form method="post" style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 25px; background-color:white;">
        <input type="hidden" name="DataHora" id="DataVotacao" value="" readonly />
        <input type="text" name="IdFuncionario" id="DataVotacao" value="@(ViewBag.Funcionario)" readonly />
        <div>
            <label for="Senha">Recurso:</label>
            @Html.DropDownList("IdRecurso", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Recurso)
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Comentario">Comentário(obrigatório):</label>
            <textarea name="Comentario" required="required"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" name="ConfirmaPassword" class="btn-primary btn-block" style="position:center">Cadastrar</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Se tem o código?

Comment: Se está dizendo IdFuncionario?

Comment: Exatamente... quero colocar naquela input, idFuncionario, o valor numérico de Id que tenho alocado no meu ViewBag.Funcionario. Ou se eu deveria armazenar o Valor em TempData pra poder utilizar ai

Comment: Deu certo Thiago a resposta?

Comment: Deu, mas tem um problema.. ViewData e ViewBag se perdem após 1 redirect, certo?

Comment: Depende o que está fazendo, eu postei o exemplo, mas, parece que sua realidade é outra, o grande problema das perguntas são essas nunca estão completas, mas, pelo que você perguntou é o que eu postei! entendeu

Comment: por mais que a situação tenha uma finalidade um pouco específica, serviu pra me esclarecer algo sim e fico muito grato inclusive!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu `controller` e método utilize `ViewData`, exemplo:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["IdFuncionario"] = 1;
    return View();
}
```

e na `View` respectiva:

```
<input type="text" value="@(ViewData["IdFuncionario"])" name="IdFuncionario" />
```

é uma maneira de passar informações do `controller` para sua `View`, mas, pouco recomendável, o correto é trabalhar com [ViewModel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=viewmodel).

<sub>***Exemplos***</sub>

- [AutoMapper e ViewModel com campos iguais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109305/automapper-e-viewmodel-com-campos-iguais)
- [Como passar multiplos viewmodel para uma única view?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34380/como-passar-multiplos-viewmodel-para-uma-%C3%BAnica-view)
- [É correto utilizar List com ViewModel?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220625/%C3%89-correto-utilizar-list-com-viewmodel)
- [Como funciona o ViewModel no asp.net mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/130770/como-funciona-o-viewmodel-no-asp-net-mvc)

Nesse [link lhe explica a diferença entre ViewBag, ViewData e TempData](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/What-is-ViewData-ViewBag-and-TempData-MVC-Option), [nesse link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata) e [nesse outro link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105806/persistir-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-usando-viewbag/219698#219698)